# Pandas dataframe how to merge 2 dfs based on timedelta?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-munging

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = a1 a2 recorded_at
       1. 2. 2020-03-18 00:00:01
       8. 1. 2021-04-15 04:00:10
       9. 0. 2021-03-18 12:40:30

df2 = b1 b2 DateTime
       7. 8. 2020-03-18 00:00:01
       2. 4. 2020-03-18 00:00:04
       2. 6. 2021-04-15 04:00:12
       4. 2. 2021-03-18 12:40:40
```

I want to merge them by comparing `recorded_at` to `DateTime`, and taking all rows that within 4 seconds after.
So I will get:

```
df_new = a1 a2 recorded_at DateTime b1 b2
       1. 2. 2020-03-18 00:00:01 2020-03-18 00:00:01 7 8 
       1. 2. 2020-03-18 00:00:01 2020-03-18 00:00:04 2 4 
       8. 1. 2021-04-15 04:00:10 2021-04-15 04:00:12 2 6
```

How can I do it?

Comment: why do you have twice row 1 of df1?

Comment: Do you expect each row of df2 to be matching more than one row of df1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't expect to have more that one row of df1 that matches a single row of df2, then an efficient solution would be a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). Else, the `merge` computation will be quadratic, so greatly dependent on the size of each input.:

```
df1['recorded_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['recorded_at'])
df2['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DateTime'])

out = (pd
 .merge_asof(df2.sort_values(by='DateTime'), df1.sort_values(by='recorded_at'), 
             left_on='DateTime', right_on='recorded_at',
             direction='backward', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('4s')
             )
 .dropna(subset=['recorded_at'])
)
```

output:

```
    b1   b2            DateTime   a1   a2         recorded_at
0  7.0  8.0 2020-03-18 00:00:01  1.0  2.0 2020-03-18 00:00:01
1  2.0  4.0 2020-03-18 00:00:04  1.0  2.0 2020-03-18 00:00:01
3  2.0  6.0 2021-04-15 04:00:12  8.0  1.0 2021-04-15 04:00:10
```

Comment: Thanks, the data is very large (df1 is 100K rows and df2 is ~2.5M), is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1.0, 2.0, "2020-03-18 00:00:01"],
    [8.0, 1.0, "2021-04-15 04:00:10"],
    [19.0, 0.0, "2021-03-18 12:40:30"],
    
], columns=["a1", "a2", "recorded_at"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    [7.0, 8.0, "2020-03-18 00:00:01"],
    [2.0, 4.0, "2020-03-18 00:00:04"],
    [2.0, 6.0, "2021-04-15 04:00:12"],
    [4.0, 2.0, "2021-03-18 12:40:40"],
    
], columns=["a1", "a2", "recorded_at"])
```

Convert to pandas datetime

```
df1["recorded_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["recorded_at"])
df2["recorded_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["recorded_at"])
```

Merging the df to create combinations

```
result = df1.merge(df2, how="cross")
```

Finding the time delta

```
result["diff"] = abs(result["recorded_at_x"] - result["recorded_at_y"])
```

Extracting the result

```
from datetime import timedelta
result[result["diff"] < timedelta(seconds=4)]
```

Result:

```
a1_x    a2_x    recorded_at_x   a1_y    a2_y    recorded_at_y   diff
0   1.0 2.0 2020-03-18 00:00:01 7.0 8.0 2020-03-18 00:00:01 0 days 00:00:00
1   1.0 2.0 2020-03-18 00:00:01 2.0 4.0 2020-03-18 00:00:04 0 days 00:00:03
6   8.0 1.0 2021-04-15 04:00:10 2.0 6.0 2021-04-15 04:00:12 0 days 00:00:02
```

It works for the sample input. but you may need a better strategy if your data is huge.